# Cannot recreate a REST API Call from Postman to C#

Tags: c#, api, rest, postman

I'm trying to make a POST request to an API, and have successfully done this in Postman.
Now, because Postman offers code snippets, I can just copy-paste this to a C# application and get the exact same result.

Here's the problem: The auth expires.
If I make a call in Postman and copy the nonce, signature, and timestamp values into my application and use it that way, it works fine for a few minutes. Eventually it expires and the call doesn't work, it returns a 0005. Therefore, I have to generate the signature, nonce, and timestamp values myself, in my application.

I already spent so many hours trying to do this but I can't figure out why it's not working. I tried several ways, but the one that seems to have gotten me the furthest is the below:

The following code is given by Postman after successfully making the call (using RestSharp):

```
var client = new RestClient("api-url.com");
client.Timeout = -1;
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.AddHeader("Authorization", "OAuth oauth_consumer_key=\"xxxx5004bbf7xxxxxx3d3e15633f01xx\",oauth_token=\"xxx894c7c76c4axxx93d833804615xxx\",oauth_signature_method=\"HMAC-SHA1\",oauth_timestamp=\"1605587985\",oauth_nonce=\"TNTCB73am0T\",oauth_version=\"1.0\",oauth_signature=\"6P7uvtxxxsEv1pz6JfxxxxlEmDY%3D\"");
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
request.AddParameter("application/json", "{\r\n    \"start\": {\"from\": 1604542428000, \"to\": 1605147228000},\r\n    \"status\": [\"CLOSE\"]\r\n}\r\n",  ParameterType.RequestBody);
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
```

Then, I use the following to get the Base64 of the signature string

```
public static string GetSignatureBaseString(string TimeStamp, string Nonce)
{
    //1.Convert the HTTP Method to uppercase and set the output string equal to this value.
    string Signature_Base_String = "Get";
    Signature_Base_String = Signature_Base_String.ToUpper();

    //2.Append the ‘&’ character to the output string.
    Signature_Base_String = Signature_Base_String + "&";

    //3.Percent encode the URL and append it to the output string.
    string PercentEncodedURL = Uri.EscapeDataString(GetAppleApiUrl.GetUrl(AppleApiUrl.SESSION_TOKEN));
    Signature_Base_String = Signature_Base_String + PercentEncodedURL;

    //4.Append the ‘&’ character to the output string.
    Signature_Base_String = Signature_Base_String + "&";

    //5.append parameter string to the output string.
    Signature_Base_String = Signature_Base_String + Uri.EscapeDataString("oauth_consumer_key=" + Settings.SettingsManager.consumer_key);
    Signature_Base_String = Signature_Base_String + Uri.EscapeDataString("&oauth_token=" + Settings.SettingsManager.access_token);
    Signature_Base_String = Signature_Base_String + Uri.EscapeDataString("&oauth_signature_method=" +"HMAC-SHA1");
    Signature_Base_String = Signature_Base_String + Uri.EscapeDataString("&oauth_timestamp=" + TimeStamp);
    Signature_Base_String = Signature_Base_String + Uri.EscapeDataString("&oauth_nonce=" + Nonce);
    Signature_Base_String = Signature_Base_String + Uri.EscapeDataString("&oauth_version=" + "1.0");

    return Signature_Base_String;
}
```

Finally, to get the sha1 hash

```
public static string GetSha1Hash(string key, string message)
{
    var encoding = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();

    byte[] keyBytes = encoding.GetBytes(key);
    byte[] messageBytes = encoding.GetBytes(message);

    string Sha1Result = string.Empty;

    using (HMACSHA1 SHA1 = new HMACSHA1(keyBytes))
    {
        var Hashed = SHA1.ComputeHash(messageBytes);
        Sha1Result = Convert.ToBase64String(Hashed);
    }

    return Sha1Result;
}
```

The OAuth 1.0 string it outputs and sends to the server is as follows:

```
OAuth oauth_consumer_key="c3e75004bbfxxxxxxx5f0104",oauth_token="e90xxxxxx38046158d3",oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",oauth_timestamp="1605588743",oauth_nonce="MTYwNTU4ODc0Mw%3D%3D",oauth_version="1.0",oauth_signature="4jKad%2xxxxxxSV%xxxxxxxxxxxMP%2FI%3D"
```

The way I combine this is simply to replace the keys in the successful Postman call with a string format {0} {1} {2} etc with the values generated by the two functions: key & access token is fine, timestamp I get from the current time obv, nonce is the base64 of the timestamp, and then the signature is the hash on the base64 signature from funct1 using secret & tokensecret.

Which looks a lot like the Postman once (except that their nonce is always very short compared to mine but I assume that's not related to the problem).

Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong?

Edit: Extra code

The way I use all the above:

```
var timeStamp = (System.Convert.ToInt32((DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1)).TotalSeconds)).ToString();
var nonce = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(timeStamp)).ToString();
SortedDictionary<string, string> @params = new SortedDictionary<string, string>();
@params.Add("application/json", "{" + Constants.vbCrLf + "    \"start\": {\"from\": 1604542428000, \"to\": 1605147228000}," + Constants.vbCrLf + "    \"status\": [\"CLOSE\"]" + Constants.vbCrLf + "}" + Constants.vbCrLf);
string b64sig = GetSignatureBaseString(timeStamp, nonce);
string signature = GetSha1Hash("secret-key", b64sig);
```

Then I insert all the values I have into the OAuth string and make the request. It returns a 0005 auth error. About the body params, I need to have these in order to get a response. This works fine if I just use the Postman nonce, timestamp and signature so I believe it's not related to the problem though. I don't need to include the body params to generate a signature right?

Comment: Can you share the code which generates timestamp and nonce? Also how you generating signature from SingagutureBaseString?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Hi, thank you for the reply. I use the following to generate timestamp:
    var timeStamp = (System.Convert.ToInt32((DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1)).TotalSeconds)).ToString();

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya The signature is generated by escaping the result of GetSha1Hash on the signature64basestring using secret-key.

EscapeDataString(GetSha1Hash("secret-key", b64sig)). It's messy in a comment so I will add it all to the OP.

Comment: The way you are generating signature base string is not correct... you can refer documentation from twitter [here](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/authentication/oauth-1-0a/creating-a-signature) for how to generate base string.

Comment: And once you generate proper signature base ,you need to generate signature using both clientsecret and tokensecret if you have token secret or only use client secret to generatethe signature..

Comment: You can refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35677711/generate-oauth1-signature-in-c-sharp too..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generate OAuth1 signature in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35677711/generate-oauth1-signature-in-c-sharp)

Comment: This is one of the posts I have been trying to adapt as well, but can't get it to work. I tried from zero again with that link while also reading the Twitter documentation, but cannot get it to work. I tried copy pasting the two code snippets exactly as they are, declaring my keys/secrets in variables and simply plugging it in. I then got the current timestamp and a nonce, created the baseSignature through code snippet #1, and hashed it with escped secretkey + & + escaped tokensecret. I then inserted these values into the request code snippet that Postman gives (which works with their values)

Comment: And that also gives 0005...